# How to add a telephone link via wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to add links in the form `<a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555">555-555-555</a>` arbitrarily into paragraphs of text on my wagtail site. These phone numbers are currently peppered throughout the site as plain text, but I want to convert them to links.

I found this old wagtail github [issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/490) where they explained why they would not add them, but the 'Special-purpose pages' use case they described seems to be different than mine: my site has these numbers in paragraphs of text on most of the content pages (blog, product, marketing, etc).

Can anyone explain how I can add telephone links that can be used throughout the site?

I am using wagtail 1.x

Answer (score 4):

To have telephone link within rich text, you'll need to create a plugin for [Hallo.js](http://hallojs.org/). Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/bergie/hallo#writing-plugins) and how Wagtail 1.13 [creates](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/tree/stable/1.13.x/wagtail/wagtailadmin/static_src/wagtailadmin/js/hallo-plugins) and [register](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/e146816b8b02e5ef08ca0acb486499d389151ba5/wagtail/wagtailadmin/wagtail_hooks.py#L187-L203) such plugins.

Be aware though that it's usually quite involved and that Wagtail 2.0 rich text editor is now Draftail and Hallo.js is deprecated. Therefore, if you create a Hallo.js plugin and upgrade to Wagtail 2.0, you'll have to [add some configuration to continue using Hallo.js](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_hallo.html) or recreate the plugin for Draftail.

FWIW, if you are interested in having a look at what would be involved with creating an plugin for Draftail, you'll need to [create an entity](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html#creating-new-entities) (also note that the API for creating entities should [receive some enhancements](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4436) in Wagtail 2.2).

Comment: Extending draftail / richtext editor is a way to go. But is a tedious task.

Answer (score 3):

With Raw HTML there is nothing to prevent editors from inserting malicious scripts into the page. Do not use this block. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/topics/streamfield.html#rawhtmlblock

A workaround would be a custom filter. Eg:

```
{{ self.text|richtext|phonify }}
```

In your templatetags.py:

```
>>> def phonify(val):
...     for tel in re.findall(r'tel:(\d+)', val):
...         tag = '<a href="tel:{}">{}</a>'.format(tel, tel)
...         val = val.replace('tel:{}'.format(tel), tag)
...     return val
...
>>> phonify('Hello tel:123 world tel:456!')
'Hello <a href="tel:123">123</a> world <a href="tel:456">456</a>!'
>>>
```

Now you can instruct editors (via help_text) to add phone numbers like `tel:5555555555`.

This example does not handle `-` and `+1`. But if you figure that out, I'll update the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up chopping up my paragraphs and including raw html where I needed to add the tel links. A bit tedious, and the styles were slightly different on some pages, but shorter than doing it any other way.